# Как проверить состояние поля в таблице у всех родителей в дереве

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Исходная таблица - дерево категорий

```
id, parent_id, state, name
```

Имеем

```
id = 4, parent_id = 0, state = 1, name = Подкатегория 0 (корневая)
id = 8, parent_id = 4, state = 0, name = Подкатегория 1
id = 15, parent_id = 8, state = 1, name = Подкатегория 2
id = 36, parent_id = 15, state = 1, name = Подкатегория 3
```

Как одним запросом проверить state у всех родителей, и если хотябы у одного state = 0, то результат выборки должен равняться 0 строк

Пробовал WITH RECURSIVE

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, state, parent_id, name) AS (
      SELECT     id,
                 state,
                 parent_id,
                 name
      FROM       t_pages
      WHERE      id = 36
      UNION ALL
      SELECT     p.id,
                 p.state,
                 p.parent_id,
                 p.name
      FROM       t_pages p
      INNER JOIN cte
                 ON p.id = cte.parent_id
                 AND p.state = 1
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Но что то не соображу, как условие задать правильно. В варианте выше всегда 1 вариант выдает(что логично)
Ну и это через чур медленно работает - 0,5сек на таблицу в 200 записей

Есть другие варианты?

**UPD: фидл https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ecdbd0252a87aed8d3c6f5b3a31e0297**

Comment: Покажите структуру таблицы, и пример данных бы.

Comment: В начале же написал. и структуру таблицы и данные

Comment: Ну поставьте себя на наше место. Мы, что, должны сами сочинять таблицу, сами писать запросы для вставки записей?..  Добавьте SQL запросы для создания таблицы и добавления записей, и дело сразу пойдет быстрее.

Comment: В смысле сами? одна таблица, всего, поля таблицы указаны. Зачем вам запросы добавления в базу и создания базы, если я только про выборку спрашиваю. Все уже создано, ничего меняться не будет никогда. Нет никаких запросов создания таблиц и добавления записей и не будет. Есть готовая таблица с обычным деревом подкатегорий. Странные какие то запросы у вас.

Comment: @Alex объясню. Чтобы вам помочь с **другими вариантами**, очевидно, нужно тоже попробовать их построить и выполнить, чтобы дать их вам. Для этого нужен небольшой дамп.(или что-то загруженное сюда: http://sqlfiddle.com). Если вам нужно лишь направление, куда копать - то да, данные не нужны.

Comment: *если хотябы у одного state = 0, то результат выборки должен равняться 0 строк* А если нет? определяйте задачу ПОЛНОСТЬЮ. PS. Если надо просто проверить, есть ли родители с нулевым статусом, то никакая рекурсия нахрен не нужна.

Comment: @СергейМишин Пожалуйста, не рекомендуйте в качестве fiddle эту сбойную хрень. dbfiddle.uk или db-fiddle.com гораздо стабильнее.

Comment: @Akina это был пример. Я ничего не рекомендовал

Comment: @СергейМишин Но ить автор-то пойдёт (если пойдёт, конечно) туда, куда послали...

Comment: @Akina а если нет, то возвращается текущая строка, которая с id = 36. Собственно сейчас она и возвращается, надо только условие дописать правильно, чтобы если хоть у одного родителя state = 0 то текущая строка перестала возвращаться, то есть результат должен быть 0 строк.

Comment: *а если нет, то возвращается текущая строка, которая с id = 36* В SQL нет такого понятия, как "текущая строка" (пока мы не имеем дела с триггером, курсором или иной итерационной технологией). PS. Я правильно понимаю, что на самом деле "результат должен быть 0 строк" в случае, если имеется родитель со state=0 **у записи с заданным значением id**?

Comment: @Akina да, верно. Если все родительские state = 1 то возвращается эта самая запись с id = 36

Comment: Всё правильно @СергейМишин говорит. Как можно написать ответ и не проверить? И как проверить - без примера БД?.. Никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @num:=6;

WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, parent_id, state FROM t_pages p WHERE p.id = @num
         UNION ALL
         SELECT p.id, p.parent_id, p.state FROM t_pages p JOIN cte ON p.id = cte.parent_id )
SELECT *
FROM t_pages 
WHERE id = @num
  AND ( SELECT MIN(state) FROM cte ) > 0
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=503d6a0a4f31ecd5bebf6154b7f9e939)

Comment: Не робит, id имеет не определенное значение. MIN(state) мне не понятно что делает. У state всего 2 состояния 1/0 включен пункт меню, или выключен

Comment: @Alex *id имеет не определенное значение* Не понял тогда, что означали слова про "текущую запись", и какого лешего в запросе делало условие `WHERE id = 36`, которое я взял без изменения. Запрос либо возвращает запись с `id=36`, если все родители имеют `state=1`, либо не возвращает, если у хотя бы одного родителя `state=0`. *MIN(state) мне не понятно что делает.* Не поверишь - выбирает минимальное значение. Если есть хотя бы один ноль - она вернёт ноль, а если ни одного нуля нет (все - единицы) - она вернёт единицу. И сделай уже, наконец, fiddle...

Comment: @Akinа про MIN(state) - сори, select проворонил ))) Запрос либо возвращает запись с id=36, если все родители имеют state=1, либо не возвращает, если у хотя бы одного родителя state=0 - все именно так и должно работать, вы верно все поняли! Добавил фидл в шапку

Comment: @Alex *Добавил фидл в шапку* Туфту ты добавил... вот ГДЕ в твоём фиддле запись `id=36`? где запись `state=0`? Нельзя же быть настолько незаинтересованным в разрешении своей собственной проблемы!

Comment: @Alex откорректировал фиддль и запрос. Смотри. Для `id=7` в цепи есть запись с `state=0` (её `id=4`) - потому выводится шиш с маслом. Я для `id=6` всё ровно, и запись отдаётся.

Comment: Премного благодарен! Сейчас буду разбираться, как это работает точно. Я кстати заметил вначале нет перечисления полей - я так понимаю их можно опускать?

Comment: @Alex *вначале нет перечисления полей* Не понял фразы. * я так понимаю их можно опускать* Опускать ничего нельзя.

Comment: я про вот это WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, state, parent_id, name) AS..... - в вашем коде этого (id, state, parent_id, name) нет

Comment: Имена полей в описании структуры CTE играют роль внешних позиционных алиасов полей. Если алиаса нет - используется имя поля. Имена полей в структуре позволяют не алиасить поля в запросе. Но никто не запрещает использовать оригинальные имена полей, опуская эти алиасы, или перенести их в текст запроса. Фактически если они есть, то это просто дополнительный уровень контроля (выполняется проверка на количество полей, а также получают алиасы выражения).

Comment: понял, спасибо большое. Пошел дальше разбираться!